# How to set image position inside <td> tag to be on top-left corner while text is on the left-bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two pawns and I want to set them on the top-left corner **while** the text (cell number) is on left-bottom.

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I **want** to have:
[image]

**CSS**:

```
td {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.soldiers
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr>
<td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="0">57
<img src="Resources/images/player_2.png" class="soldiers">
<img src="Resources/images/player_1.png" class="soldiers">
</td>
<td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="1">58</td>
<td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="2">59</td>
<td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="3">60</td>
<td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="4">61</td>
<td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="5">62</td>
<td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="6">63</td>
<td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="7">64</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try adding .soldiers
{
    position:relative; left:0; top:0; width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

Comment: You can apply even and odd with `td:nth-child(even) { }` and `td:nth-child(odd) { }` http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/v6qrfvrd/1/ only foregoing IE 6 support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the number in a `span` and position it at the bottom, and `vertical-align: top;` everything else.

```css
td {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: left;        
    border: 1px solid black;        
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>57</span>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/ff6a00/ff6a00" alt="" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/fb235e/fb235e" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like the colors! +1

Comment: What is good about your solution is that it does not depend on the dimensions of the two icon images.  Wrapping the number in a `span` is a small price to pay for getting a lot of control over the design.

Comment: [See my answer for a simple and elegant solution to completely eliminate the unnecessary `span` element with the number.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26068984/1729885)

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, very clever approach :).. if the question was "the most efficient way to make a chess board" I would of totally voted yours. Given the question at hand with the OPs approach, id say the extra span tag isn't unnecessary and is a good answer because it doesn't re-factor everything.

Answer (score 2):

You are using way too much code. Using [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) you can make this problem completely trivial.

[See this demonstration fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud5b6aor/). I generate the board completely in JS, allowing you to use it in an array, and then use CSS counters ([universally supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters)) with [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to put the numbers in there with absolute positioning.

For the background coloring I use trivial nested `nth-child` selectors. Then just apply `vertical-align:top` to the cell and let the flow do the job - I use text content here but images will flow the same as they're both inline content.

All the CSS needed:

```
table {
    counter-reset:number 65;
}
td {
    border:1px solid black;
    counter-increment:number -1;
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even), tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#aaf;
}
td:after {
    content:counter(number);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[Sample linked again here to be sure you don't miss it](http://jsfiddle.net/ud5b6aor/).

Answer (score 0):

**A way to do it without extra mark-up**

Since you specified the dimensions of the icons (20x20), you can take advantage of that
and use the `nth-child` selector to position the two icons to the top left of the table cell.

However, you do need to set the `left` offset to a specific value based on the dimension
given in `.soldier`.

```css
td {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.soldiers {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
img:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="0">
      57
      <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" class="soldiers">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10" class="soldiers">
    </td>
    <td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="1">58</td>
    <td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="2">59</td>
    <td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="3">60</td>
    <td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="4">61</td>
    <td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="5">62</td>
    <td class="oddCellBorder" row="0" col="6">63</td>
    <td class="evenCellBorder" row="0" col="7">64</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```